# OpenSSL EdDSA Specify Key Size

Tags: node.js, openssl, elliptic-curve

I need to generate some keypairs with the ed25519 curve for NodeJS's `elliptic` module for a project I'm working on. After some searching, a discovered that this can be done with the following command:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -out private.pem
```

However, this always generates a key of 64 characters in length. I wish to specify a certain size for the key though. Is this possible using OpenSSL? If not, could I please be pointed to a method by which to securely generate such keys with a set size elsewhere?

Also, I am very new to elliptic curve cryptography, and don't quite yet understand how EdDSA keys are generated. So please tell me if I've completely failed at understanding this, and please explain where I've gone terribly wrong if so.

Comment: Do you mean 64 *hex* characters? Said differently, 32 *bytes*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ed25519 private keys are by definition 32-bytes in length. From section 5.1.5 of RFC8032:

> The private key is 32 octets (256 bits, corresponding to b) of
> cryptographically secure random data.  See [RFC4086] for a discussion
> about randomness.

I don't know where you get 64 characters in your question above. I might expect that you are looking at the encoded length - but that also doesn't make sense.

If I do this:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -out private.pem
```

Then I get a PEM encoded private key which is 119 bytes in length. This is encoded according to section 7 of RFC8410. You can look at the contents like this:

```
openssl asn1parse -in private.pem
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  46 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=   5 cons: SEQUENCE          
    7:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :ED25519
   12:d=1  hl=2 l=  34 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:0420F897797B25D84588192CE39F0E6311954034CB80F6D8CD648A3BCBFC2346A83E
```

The actual raw private key itself is encoded as an OCTET STRING *inside* the OCTET  STRING shown above (in accordance with RFC 8410). As you can see above that octet string starts at offset 12, with a header length of 2 - so the data itself is at offset 14:

```
openssl asn1parse -in private.pem -offset 14
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:F897797B25D84588192CE39F0E6311954034CB80F6D8CD648A3BCBFC2346A83E
```

Which shows you a private key of 32 bytes in length as expected.

Some software may store keys in different formats not conformant with RFC8410 (e.g. by storing the private key and public key together) - so if you've loaded this key into something else then that might explain where the 64 is coming from. You can't use OpenSSL to generate those formats though.

However the bottom line is, ed25519 private keys are always 32-bytes and you can't change it. Its a fundamental property of the algorithm.

Comment: `ed25519 private keys are by definition 32-bytes in length`.  RSA keys have customizable length to future proof. You can always strengthen by increasing length. Are you saying that ed25519 has no such future-proofing feature?

Comment: Yes - that's correct

Comment: Speaking generally, if an algorithm is broken, making it longer won't save you. "The very concept of having multiple “security levels” for raw cryptography primitives is mostly an artefact of the historical military roots of cryptography, rather than a serious consideration in the modern world." [Source](https://soatok.blog/2022/05/19/guidance-for-choosing-an-elliptic-curve-signature-algorithm-in-2022/), which recommends ed25519.

Answer (score 0):

@arctic_hen7 you probably meant **32 bytes** rather than **32 bits** here:

1. "...ed25519 private keys are by definition 32-**bits** in length. From section 5.1.5 of..."
2. "...The private key is **32 octets** (256 bits, corresponding to b)..."
3. "...Which shows you a private key of **32 bytes** in length as expected...."
4. "...However the bottom line is, ed25519 private keys are always **32-bits** and you can't change it...."