# Reading HEX formatted private key back into OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, hex, ed25519

I generate an **ED25519** key-pair:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 | openssl pkey -text
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIEp53xeY8qoDU5mi2h7O//pJnI5CXWHWI9SVhgjKq1kt
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
ED25519 Private-Key:
priv:
    4a:79:df:17:98:f2:aa:03:53:99:a2:da:1e:ce:ff:
    fa:49:9c:8e:42:5d:61:d6:23:d4:95:86:08:ca:ab:
    59:2d
pub:
    c8:af:94:9f:f9:a2:10:95:2d:54:34:75:be:94:2d:
    e7:9a:ef:9c:4e:7c:6d:80:ae:fd:25:e3:a4:d5:b0:
    e3:30
```

Then I store the **priv** key in HEX for later use.

```
$ hex=4a:79:df:17:98:f2:aa:03:53:99:a2:da:1e:ce:ff:fa:49:9c:8e:42:5d:61:d6:23:d4:95:86:08:ca:ab:59:2d
```

According to another answer, the following should get me the original data, but instead I get an error:

```
$ echo $hex | xxd -r -ps > ed25519.der
$ cat ed25519.der | openssl pkey -inform der -noout -text
Could not read key from <stdin>
```

**How can I correctly regenerate the ED25519 public key from the HEX private key?**

Comment: Why not use the original format?

Comment: `hex` is the hex encoded *raw* private key, but you need for `openssl pkey` the *DER encoded* key (which you get by Base64 decoding `MC4CAQ...`), s. online  http://tpcg.io/_IS1SCN

Comment: If you only have the raw private key 4a79...592d, you have to generate the DER encoded private key from it. In the case of Ed25519 simply prefix with 302e020100300506032b657004220420 (see the online example linked above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I correctly regenerate the ED25519 public key from the HEX private key?**

As explained in [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco)'s comment, `hex` is the encoded *raw* private key, i.e. only the 32-bytes of the ED25519 key.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60704447/105315) for more details.

However `openssl` expects an input in the OpenSSL DER or PEM formats.

So there will be two steps:

1. Recreate an OpenSSL private key from the 32-byte hex key.
2. Create an OpenSSL public key from the OpenSSL private key.

## Recreate an OpenSSL private key from the 32-byte hex key.

In order to do that, you just need to add the following extra `header` bytes before the 32-byte `hex` key:

```
##### Creating a private DER key from the private hex key:
header=30:2e:02:01:00:30:05:06:03:2b:65:70:04:22:04:20
hex=4a:79:df:17:98:f2:aa:03:53:99:a2:da:1e:ce:ff:fa:49:9c:8e:42:5d:61:d6:23:d4:95:86:08:ca:ab:59:2d
echo "${header}${hex}" | xxd -r -ps > ed25519.der
```

You can now check the contents of the  created DER file as follows:

```
##### Check contents of DER file:
cat ed25519.der | openssl pkey -inform der -noout -text
```

Output:

```
ED25519 Private-Key:
priv:
    4a:79:df:17:98:f2:aa:03:53:99:a2:da:1e:ce:ff:
    fa:49:9c:8e:42:5d:61:d6:23:d4:95:86:08:ca:ab:
    59:2d
pub:
    c8:af:94:9f:f9:a2:10:95:2d:54:34:75:be:94:2d:
    e7:9a:ef:9c:4e:7c:6d:80:ae:fd:25:e3:a4:d5:b0:
    e3:30
```

Optionally, you can also create a private key in the PEM format as follows:

```
##### Creating a private PEM key from the private DER key:
openssl pkey -in ed25519.der -outform pem -out ed25519.pem
```

Contents of ed25519.pem:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIEp53xeY8qoDU5mi2h7O//pJnI5CXWHWI9SVhgjKq1kt
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

## Create an OpenSSL public key from the OpenSSL private key.

To create a public key in the DER format:

```
##### Creating a public DER key from the private DER key:
openssl pkey -in ed25519.der -outform der -pubout -out ed25519.pub.der
```

To create a public key in the PEM format:

```
##### Creating a public PEM key from the private DER key:
openssl pkey -in ed25519.der -outform pem -pubout -out ed25519.pub.pem
```

Contents of ed25519.pub.pem:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEAyK+Un/miEJUtVDR1vpQt55rvnE58bYCu/SXjpNWw4zA=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

## Optional: Printing out the 32-byte hex keys of the generated DER or PEM files for checking

```
##### Check contents of keys, but this time without cat:
echo "=== Private DER key ==="
openssl pkey -inform der -in ed25519.der -noout -text
echo "=== Private PEM key ==="
openssl pkey -inform pem -in ed25519.pem -noout -text
echo "=== Public DER key ==="
openssl pkey -pubin -inform der -in ed25519.pub.der -noout -text
echo "=== Public PEM key ==="
openssl pkey -pubin -inform pem -in ed25519.pub.pem -noout -text
```

Output:

```
=== Private DER key ===
ED25519 Private-Key:
priv:
    4a:79:df:17:98:f2:aa:03:53:99:a2:da:1e:ce:ff:
    fa:49:9c:8e:42:5d:61:d6:23:d4:95:86:08:ca:ab:
    59:2d
pub:
    c8:af:94:9f:f9:a2:10:95:2d:54:34:75:be:94:2d:
    e7:9a:ef:9c:4e:7c:6d:80:ae:fd:25:e3:a4:d5:b0:
    e3:30
=== Private PEM key ===
ED25519 Private-Key:
priv:
    4a:79:df:17:98:f2:aa:03:53:99:a2:da:1e:ce:ff:
    fa:49:9c:8e:42:5d:61:d6:23:d4:95:86:08:ca:ab:
    59:2d
pub:
    c8:af:94:9f:f9:a2:10:95:2d:54:34:75:be:94:2d:
    e7:9a:ef:9c:4e:7c:6d:80:ae:fd:25:e3:a4:d5:b0:
    e3:30
=== Public DER key ===
ED25519 Public-Key:
pub:
    c8:af:94:9f:f9:a2:10:95:2d:54:34:75:be:94:2d:
    e7:9a:ef:9c:4e:7c:6d:80:ae:fd:25:e3:a4:d5:b0:
    e3:30
=== Public PEM key ===
ED25519 Public-Key:
pub:
    c8:af:94:9f:f9:a2:10:95:2d:54:34:75:be:94:2d:
    e7:9a:ef:9c:4e:7c:6d:80:ae:fd:25:e3:a4:d5:b0:
    e3:30
```